# how to add a pin with image when gesture on map

Tags: swift

I would like to add a pin on the Map with an image on a gesture.
Actually the add pin on gesture feature works great but without the image because it has to be a `MKAnnotationView` and not just `MKAnnotation`.
So I got weird warnings that I'm unable to fix: [image: Image of warning]

Answer (score 1):

```
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = location.title
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
            mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }



func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }

        let identifier = "CustomAnnotation"

        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView!.canShowCallout = false
            annotationView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "map-pinpoint.png")!
        } else {
            annotationView!.annotation = annotation
        }
        return annotationView
    }
```

Comment: sorry but it's not my questions I want the pin to be add with an image when I touch the map using the gesture

Comment: But you have to call viewfor annotation to use custom pin.

Comment: sorry I didn't say it but I have it too, and when I add a pin with the gesture it doesn't add it with the good image

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the errors are because MKPinAnnotationView always use a pin image, so you can't be override. You should use MKAnnotationView instead.